# cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: adobe-air

Problem with this file `/tmp-air-nkhvxz-setup-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0`

I try to solve this problem and try to install  libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

but two links above do not work. Is there any other alternative one?

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem and I was unable to fund solution on the internet, nothing worked for me. Finally I've managed it to work simply by installing **libgtk2.0-0:i386** graphic library from the Ubuntu Software Center.

You can also type the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Comment: For beginners like myself, I suggest using Software Center, because there you can actually see that two types of libraries exists, "normal" and i386 :)

Comment: Thanks for this, after doing this I was able to load Second Life / Opensim for a client of mine who requires educational tools. in the VR world.  Really helped.  Cheers

Answer (score 8):

To fix this issue. You must install `ia32-libs-gtk`, which is a virtual package of **ia32-libs**. Also try installing **libglib2.0-dev**

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs libglib2.0-dev
```

If the above did not work then try installing

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```

The shared library you mentioned belongs to **libgtk2.0.0**. So the above command should solve the issue.

If you are running 64 bit Ubuntu, try

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

This worked in 14.04 LTS

Comment: It's not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install some libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
```